# Converter a primeira letra em caixa alta e os acentos em caixa baixa

Tags: php

Estou trazendo do BD Mysql os dados do usuário. Os nomes foram gravadas em caixa alta. Estou criando uma saudação para esse usuário pegando somente o primeiro nome.

```
list($nome,$sobrenome) = explode(" ",$pe->NomeUsuario);
```

O resultado ficou assim:

> Bem-vindo de volta TÚLIO

Porém quero deixar dessa forma:

> Bem-vindo de volta Túlio

Para isso tentei fazer a função abaixo:

```
 function converter($palavra){ //
        $minusculas = array("á", "à", "â", "ã", "ä", "é", "è", "ê", "ë", "í", "ì", "î", "ï", "ó", "ò", "ô", "õ", "ö", "ú", "ù", "û", "ü", "ç");
        $maiusculas = array("Á", "À", "Â", "Ã", "Ä", "É", "È", "Ê", "Ë", "Í", "Ì", "Î", "Ï", "Ó", "Ò", "Ô", "Õ", "Ö", "Ú", "Ù", "Û", "Ü", "Ç");
        $converter = str_replace($maiusculas, $minusculas, $palavra);
        return ucfirst($converter);
      }

 list($nome,$sobrenome) = explode(" ",converter($pe->NomeUsuario));
```

Mas o resultado é:

> TúLIO

Como posso converter TÚLIO para Túlio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se não fosse os acentos você poderia usar o ucfirst() ou ucword(), mas no caso é melhor utilizar o mb_convert_case()

```
<?php

    $string = 'TÚLIO';

    $new_string = mb_convert_case($string, MB_CASE_TITLE, 'UTF-8');

    echo $new_string; // Túlio

?>
```

Comment: Olá Rafael. Eu havia conseguido dessa forma e ia postar aqui `$converter = mb_strtolower($palavra,'UTF-8');` `return ucfirst($converter);`, mas sua solução foi melhor que a minha, pois criei uma função e resolvi em apenas 1 linha. Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Tente então dessa forma

```html
function converter($palavra){ //
        $minusculas = array("á", "à", "â", "ã", "ä", "é", "è", "ê", "ë", "í", "ì", "î", "ï", "ó", "ò", "ô", "õ", "ö", "ú", "ù", "û", "ü", "ç");
        $maiusculas = array("Á", "À", "Â", "Ã", "Ä", "É", "È", "Ê", "Ë", "Í", "Ì", "Î", "Ï", "Ó", "Ò", "Ô", "Õ", "Ö", "Ú", "Ù", "Û", "Ü", "Ç");
        $converter = str_replace($maiusculas, $minusculas, $palavra);
        return ucfirst(strtolower($converter));
      }

 list($nome,$sobrenome) = explode(" ",converter($pe->NomeUsuario));
```

Comment: Olá Nicolas. Na verdade é TÚLIO e não tulio,  ou seja, tem acento na letra ú. Já tentei dessa forma antes, mas a letra Ú fica em caixa alta.